# HTML Checkboxes uncheck after submit button

Tags: python, django, passwords

I wrote a password manager with length and checkboxes for symbols like chars/digits and special characters like !$&

Everytime I hit the submit button to generate the password the unchecked boxes are checked again (because my default is that they should be checked), but how can I make that the box is like it was before submitting the form. I tried it with an if statment in the template because I'm using django but that doesnt help. If someone has an idea how I can achieve my solution please let me know. Thanks for your help

Heres my code:

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    alphabets_b = bool(request.GET.get('alphabets'))
    digits_b = bool(request.GET.get('digits'))
    special_characters_b = bool(request.GET.get('special_characters'))
    alphabets = string.ascii_letters*alphabets_b
    digits = string.digits*digits_b
    special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()"*special_characters_b
    characters = alphabets + digits + special_characters
    if 'length' in request.GET:
        length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
        password = ''
        for i in range(length):
            password+=random.choice(characters)    
        pyperclip.copy(password)
        pyperclip.paste()
        messages.info(request, 'The password was copied to your clipboard')
        username = request.user.username
        context = {'password': password, 'length': length, 'username': username}

        return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html', context)
    username = request.user.username
    hs = {'username': username}
    return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html', hs)
```

and my template:

```
                       <form method="get" action="{% url 'home:passwordgenerator' %}">
                           <div class="fake_input">

                           <p class="fake_input_text">{{ password }}</p>
                           </div>
                                   <span class="fake_input_l">Length:</span> <select class="fake_input_drop" name="length"> 
                                       <option value="8" {% if length == 8 %}selected{% endif %}>8</option>
                                       <option value="10" {% if length == 10 %}selected{% endif %}>10</option>
                                       <option value="12" {% if length == 12 %}selected{% endif %}>12</option>
                                       <option value="14" {% if length == 14 %}selected{% endif %}>14</option>
                                       <option value="16" {% if length == 16 %}selected{% endif %}>16</option>
                                       <option value="18" {% if length == 18 %}selected{% endif %}>18</option>
                                       <option value="20" {% if length == 20 %}selected{% endif %} >20</option>
                                   </select>
                                   <span class="fake_input_l"> Alphabet Letters: <input type="checkbox" name="alphabets" checked>
                                   Digits: <input type="checkbox" name="digits" checked>
                                   Special Characters: <input type="checkbox" name="special_characters" checked></span>
                                   <button type="submit" value="Generate Password" class="fake_input_button">Generate</button>     
                       </form>
```

Comment: The input statements you've written in your template show that they are always been checked by default no matter what the user does to the field. Whenever someone loads your form, it's checked. Can you please explain more about the performance and how you want it to be like?

Comment: Yes, when I uncheck one of the boxes I want it to be unchecked until I turn it back. With the code above it changes after submitting to "checked" again. I need an if statement which checks if the boolean from the template is true and if so the box should be checked.

Comment: I think you need to save those kinds of flags in the session that the user makes during the submission. With that being said, you need to set up the session middleware and implement its structures. Then, create a new session variable that contains the situation of those checkboxes. In that scenario, I think Ajax would help you fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

you should set those checkbox values in the context and when you return on that page check those values and based on the flag marked it checked or unchecked like below :-

```
def view_passwordgenerator(request):
    username = request.user.username
    alphabets_b = bool(request.GET.get('alphabets'))
    digits_b = bool(request.GET.get('digits'))
    special_characters_b = bool(request.GET.get('special_characters'))
    ...
    context = {'username': username}
    if 'length' in request.GET:
        ...
        ...
        context.update({'password': password, 'length': length, 'alphabets_b': alphabets_b, 'digits_b': digits_b, 'special_characters_b': special_characters_b})
    else:
        context.update({'alphabets_b': True, 'digits_b': True, 'special_characters_b': True})

    return render(request, 'home/passwordgenerator.html', context)
```

And in your HTML page you should check the flags like below :-

```
<span class="fake_input_l"> 
    Alphabet Letters: <input type="checkbox" name="alphabets" {% if alphabets_b %}checked {% endif %} >
    Digits: <input type="checkbox" name="digits" {% if digits_b %}checked {% endif %}>
    Special Characters: <input type="checkbox" name="special_characters" {% if special_characters_b %}checked {% endif %}>
</span>
```